# numpy.ndarray.shape changing dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The tuple holding the dimensions of a numpy array (numpy.ndarray.shape) changes size. E.g:

```
len(numpy.array([1,2,3]).shape) -> 1, shape=(1,)
len(numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).shape) -> 2, shape=(2,3)
```

Is there any other way to get dimensions invariant to the type of the array?

Here is an example of the problem I encounter quite often:

```
mat3D = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
mat2D = np.arange(9)

def processMatrix(mat):
  if M.ndim == 2:
    return foo(mat)
  else:
    return np.array([foo(mat[:,:,c]) for c in range(mat.shape[2])])
```

Having `mat2D.shape = (3,3,1)` would simplify the code to:

```
def processMatrix(mat):
    return np.array([foo(mat[:,:,c]) for c in range(mat.shape[2])])
```

Comment: numpy.array([[1,2,3]]).shape return (1,3)

Comment: The `shape` tuple has to change size, to match the number of dimensions.  If you have N dimensions, you need N numbers to specify the size.  Could you be more specific about what you find annoying about this?  Maybe your real issue is different from what it seems.

Comment: Numpy arrays can have *N* dimensions.  E.g. `np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]).shape` is `(2,2,2)`.  The "invariant" is that `a.ndim` is `len(a.shape)`.

Comment: @DSM I often find myself to use both 1D and 2D arrays interchangeably and the shape tuple changing size requires unnecessary if-else conditions.  I guess I should just wrap everything into matrices. Unfortunately most of the functions returns arrays independently from the type of the input.

Comment: Give an example of one of your unnecessary if-else conditions.  Maybe there is another way to handle it.

Comment: `Y = [foo(X[:,c]) for c in X.shape(1)]`

Comment: Could you add that to the question, along with an explanation of the problem you encounter with that expression?

Comment: Sure. Just realized, it's also a problem of indexing, and not just the dimension of `shape`

Comment: On a side note, have look at `numpy.atleast_1d`, `numpy.atleast_2d` and `numpy.atleast_3d`.  Typically, when you want everything to have a fixed number of dimensions, you'd use one of these on all input variables.  (Also note that you can do things like `x, y, z = np.atleast_2d(x, y, z)`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).ndim
```